# C# unsafe context / pointer type of LPWStr

Tags: c#, pointers, unsafe, wchar-t

suppose we have an unsafe context, because I want to have a pointer to a wchar_t parameter which is passed from a unmanaged C++ code. For example:

```
unsafe public(int* A, ???* B)
{
    _myInt = A;
    _myString = B;
}
```

Everything is fine with the int parameter, but what about the ???* type?
I know that to marshal a wchar_t to a C# string type for this method, one can write [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] before the parameter B.
But I need some kind of a native pointer type for B in order to link this pointer to _myString field.
Is there something like wchar_t in C# or what else can I do to have the pointer B stored elsewhere in the class?
Thanks,
Jurgen

Comment: Have you tried using IntPtr?  That's usually what I use to pass around any kind of pointers from C++ that I don't want to mess with except to pass them back to C++ later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a problem with c# copying the string behind the pointer during the construction of a string... you can pull it off like this:

```
public static unsafe int Strlen(char* start)
{
  var eos = start;

  while (*(eos++) != 0);
  return (int) ((eos - start) - 1);
}

unsafe public(int* A, char* B)
{
    _myInt = A;

    _myString = new String(B, 0, Strlen(B));
}
```

The constructor used here is documented in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131423.aspx)